# How to done routing in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

First time i am working on CI project. I am having one linking issue.

header.php : (views)

```
<li class="">
      <a title="" href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/welcome/index')?>">
         <i class="icon icon-share-alt"></i> 
         <span class="text">Logout</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

In Welcome.php : (controller)

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('layouts/login');
}
```

From this i am getting this error:

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   include(F:\xampp\htdocs\payroll_crm\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\payroll_crm\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 268

please help me with the same.I did not work on routing. is there need of routing?

Comment: did you created `login.php` file in `layouts` folder in  `payroll_crm\application\views` path ?

Comment: yes i have it .

Comment: replace `site_url()` with `base_url()`

Comment: Error Clearly say that you don't have such file or directory in view?

Comment: Yes exactly @ankitsuthar

Comment: Dear @amitsutar you should add your directory structure or should check the configuration first it will help.

Comment: Check this link `https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you: Register/defined your route in `application/config/routes.php` in `$route array`?

You might wanna look: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html